# Unauthorized, The input authorization token can't serve the request

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to obtain documentdbclient using the resourcetokens. I have a redis cluster with key as user identity and value as the resourcetoken. 
I have a service that uses master key to generate resourcetokens for the user and updates them in Redis. I am using the below code to create resource token in my master service

```
  ResourceResponse<Permission> readPermissions = documentClient.readPermission("/dbs/customerdb/users/mobileuser/permissions/readperm", null);
        String accessToken=permission.getToken();
DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(HOST, MASTER_KEY,
                     ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);
```

Then i use below code to get resourcetoken and store it in redis

```
jedis.put("Client_1",readPermissions .getResource().getToken());
```

Now, at client side when i try to create documentClient using the resourcetoken

```
DocumentClient manageClient = new DocumentClient(HOST,  jedis.get("Client_1"),ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);
```

I get logs stating unauthorized and following that the error

```
Unauthorized, The input authorization token can't serve the request
```

I have created a user called mobileuser on database customerdb and permission with mode PermissionMode.Read on collection customers

I changed my code to be very sure that the tokens are not getting expired but still getting error

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get
```

colls
dxhxakm3caa=
mon, 05 jun 2017 08:56:40 gmt

below id the code that i used to get the token

```
    ResourceResponse<Permission> permissions=documentClient.readPermission("/dbs/customerdd/users/mobileuser/permissions/readperm", null);
    System.out.println(permissions.getResource().getResourceLink());
    DocumentClient managedClient=new DocumentClient(HOST,permissions.getResource().getToken(), ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);
    FeedResponse<Document> response = managedClient.queryDocuments(collection.getResource().getSelfLink(), "SELECT customers.source FROM customers where customers.source='direct-mail'", null);
    Iterator<Document> itr = response.getQueryIterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Document doc=itr.next();
        System.out.println(doc.get("source"));
    }
```

Any pointer will be of a great help

Comment: `"readPermissions .getResource().getToken()"` - I hope quotes are just typo in the question?

Comment: Yes these are typos... I have edited them. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

> Unauthorized, The input authorization token can't serve the request

As far as I know, the default valid timespan of [the resource token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens) is one hour. And if the resource token expires, subsequent requests receive a 401 unauthorized exception, please make sure if the resource token is expired when you retrieve it from Redis cache.

**Update:**

> If i use the overloaded constructor of DocumentClient and pass the PermissionFeed then it works

[DocumentClient class](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/index.html?com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/DocumentClient.html) has two constructors as below, and when you use `new DocumentClient(HOST,  jedis.get("Client_1"),ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);`, it seems that it recognizes `jedis.get("Client_1")` that you passed as a string and use the second constructor to initialize a new instance, which would be the cause of the issue.

[image]

Comment: No i don't think so that is the problem as I am calling the API just after generating the code.

Comment: If you directly access resource with the resource token that you generate (not store it in Redis cache and retrieve it), does the resource token is valid?

Comment: To reconfirm that the token is not getting expired i changed my code. Now i am reading the permission again and then getting token to make the request but still getting error  java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get
colls
dxhxakm3caa=
mon, 05 jun 2017 08:56:40 gmt

Comment: If i use the overloaded constructor of DocumentClient and pass the PermissionFeed then it works

Comment: based on below link if you see you can either pass MasterKey or a resource token or else pass permission feed. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.documentclient.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Now if i pass resource token that i get by using Permission.getToken() method i get Unauthorized error, but if i add same Permission object that i used for getting token in permission List and pass it. It works. I Am not getting the reason for this behaviour

Comment: [The link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.documentclient.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you provide is for .NET SDK, and it has four overloads. As I mentioned in the reply, [DocumentClient class](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/index.html?com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/DocumentClient.html) in JAVA SDK seems only have two constructor overloads, we should pass either List<Permission> type permissionFeed or String type masterKey.